# Using the rubber gem to deploy on different types of instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, amazon-ec2

I am using the rubber gem and I have set it up to use m1.small instance type in the rubber-setup file.
Now I want to complicate my deployment by deploying to different types of instances (high-cpu machines, medium instances and small instances).
How can I configure rubber to use different instances for different roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the "image_type" key in the rubber YAML files.

Here is how I set my database instances to use a m1.large instance type:

```
roles:
  db:
    cloud_providers:
      aws:
        image_type: m1.large
```